# some errors in a userform to add data into multiple sheets/tables

Tags: excel, vba, userform

Can you help me fix these errors? 
The code runs but puts data in the wrong place for all sheets I put notes in comments below on where it's doing this...
AND I need a check for duplicate names before adding userform values
Here's my userform code:

```
Private Sub cmdAddVol_Click()

    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("VOLUNTEERS")
    Dim wsArray As Worksheet

    For Each wsArray In Sheets(Array("VOLUNTEERS", "OCTOBER", "NOVEMBER", "DECEMBER", "JANUARY", "FEBRUARY", "MARCH", "APRIL", "MAY", "JUNE", "JULY", "AUGUST", "SEPTEMBER", "FY TOTALS"))
    With wsArray

    'first clear all filters *(this is not working)*
        'This removes any filtering in order to display all of the data but it does not remove the filter arrows
        If .AutoFilterMode Then
            If .FilterMode Then
                .ShowAllData
            End If
        Else
            If .FilterMode Then
                .ShowAllData
            End If
        End If

        'find  first empty row in database
    lRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1

          'check for a Name
    If Trim(Me.txtLastName.Value) = "" Then
      Me.txtFirstName.SetFocus
      MsgBox "Please enter First and Last Name"
      Exit Sub
    End If

         'validate name is not in database
         *'need code for error duplicate check*

           'copy the data to the database in all sheets(14)
           *' this is only working for VOLUNTEERS sheet, all others are not putting row in table end, but in 2 rows below table*
      .Cells(lRow, 1).Value = Me.cbStatus.Value
      .Cells(lRow, 2).Value = Me.txtLastName.Value
      .Cells(lRow, 3).Value = Me.txtFirstName.Value
    End With
    Next

     'copy only values below in VOLUNTEERS sheet col 4 & 5 at newROw
     *'this in not working--its putting data in next row after 1row* 
    With ws
       .Cells(lRow, 4).Value = Me.cbVolType.Value
       .Cells(lRow, 5).Value = Me.txtDateStart.Value

    'clear the data in box
    Me.txtFirstName.Value = ""
    Me.txtLastName.Value = ""
    Me.cbStatus.Value = ""
    Me.txtFirstName.SetFocus
    End With
    End Sub

    Private Sub cmdClose_Click()
        Unload Me
    End Sub

    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim cStatus As Range
    Dim cType As Range
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Lists")

    For Each cStatus In ws.Range("lst_Status")
      With Me.cbStatus
        .AddItem cStatus.Value
    ''.List(.ListCount - 1, 1) = cStatus.Offset(0, 1).Value
      End With
    Next cStatus

    For Each cType In ws.Range("lst_Type")
      With Me.cbVolType
        .AddItem cType.Value
      End With
    Next cType

    Me.txtDateStart.Value = Format(Date, "Medium Date")

    Me.cbStatus.SetFocus

    End Sub

    Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, _
      CloseMode As Integer)
      If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then
        Cancel = True
        MsgBox "Please use the Close Form button!"
      End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: Most likely cause: `lRow = ws.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows,   SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues).Row + 1` this refers to the row in `Worksheets("VOLUNTEERS")`. You may be meant to use `wsArray`, not `ws`. Why do you have to loop through those worksheets? Are you trying to add details to all the worksheets if none existed per worksheet?

Comment: YES -I want array.  I am trying to add 3 values STATUS (A)  last (B) and First (C) to a new row (volunteer) in each MONTHLY sheet. and 2 add'l values (TYPE & DATE) to the 1st sheet of VOLUNTEERS...but now I'm rethinking this nightmare....The only reason I was adding to all sheets is because I couldn't figure out how to add monthly hours to only ACTIVE vols that month and be able to add hours to a summary for the year end.

Comment: I think I could just add volunteer contact data to the 1st sheet and use the NAME columns as a pull down list on each monthly sheet...Should I concatenate the names to one cell rather than 2 (col)?

Comment: If *VOLUNTEERS* stores all contact details, you can make the NAME column as drop down list via named range and data validation. But need to know why the userform is used and what command button **cmdAddVol**'s goals are, so the workflow is clear.

Comment: thanks for the tip!  Here's what I did INSTEAD of a combo box to ADD volunteers to ALL sheets:  I used the VOLUNTEER sheet NAME column as a primary key and listed it for a pulldown. I had to merge the anme from 2 columns (last FIrst to last, first on one column. Using a contextures video to improve the pull down to allow for larger font and autofill, NOW I only need to add the volunteer to the MONTHLY log sheet if they are active and I don't have to contend with all 500 rows in all sheets;)

Comment: now new volunteers only need to be added to the primary sheet and can be selected during month activity. Makes it much easier to identify who worked that month;)